# React - run dev-server

Tags: reactjs, npm, cmd

- clone the git code in react.
- install npm.

problem -

for some reason i cant run dev-server . 
I treid this two command on cmd 
1. npm run dev-server

"sample" for  1 of the error i get -

> **Warning: React version not specified in eslint-plugin-react settings. See
>   https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react#configuration .
>   C:\Users\Alon\Desktop\skillz_fontend\src\components\Inputs\GooglePlacesInput.jsx
>   57:30  error  Missing semicolon  semi**

2. npm start -

> **C:\Users\Alon\Desktop\skillz_fontend>npm start npm ERR! missing script: start npm ERR! npm ERR! Did you mean this? npm ERR!     stats
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>
>   C:\Users\Alon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-11-17T22_59_13_787Z-debug.log**

thanks Alon

Answer (score 47):

When you see a warning like this:

```
Warning: React version not specified in eslint-plugin-react settings. See https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react#configuration .
```

Try adding React version settings in your eslint configuration file, such as `.eslintrc.js`, like below:

[image]

```
// .eslintrc.js
{
  ...
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Also you can add the settings object above to `.eslintrc.json` and it works for me and I no longer see the warning message.

Answer (score 3):

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    jest: true,
    'react-native/react-native': true,
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
    'plugin:react-native/all',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['react', 'react-hooks', 'react-native'],
  rules: {
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [1, { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] }],
    'global-require': 0,
    'operator-linebreak': [2, 'before'],
  },

  settings: {
    react: {
      version: "detect"
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: No explanation, almost 1 year later than the accepted answer and it's the same

Comment: For anyone still looking at this explanation: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react#configuration